# Does split("\n") add a new line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

File abc's content:

```
a
b
c
```

The code is

```
data_fh = open("abc")
str = data_fh.read()
arr = str.split("\n")
print len(arr)
data_fh.seek(0)
arr = data_fh.read().splitlines()
print len(arr)
```

but the output is:

```
4
3
```

so why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a trailing newline:

```
>>> s = 'a\nb\nc\n'  # <-- notice the \n at the end
>>>
>>> s.split('\n')
['a', 'b', 'c', '']
>>>
>>> s.splitlines()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Notice that [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) leaves an empty string at the end whereas [`splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) does not.

As an aside, you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name since that's already taken by a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: but file's content is 'a\nb\nc',no trailing newline!

Comment: @user1936154 What do you see if you print `arr`?

Comment: @user1936154 I'm fairly certain you have a trailing newline.

Comment: @user1936154: Your output contradicts your assertion. The trailing `''` proves there was a trailing newline.

Comment: what i saw in linux terminal is:

Comment: @user1936154 If you have a different problem you should post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Because `.splitlines()` does not include the empty line at the end, while `.split('\n')` returns an empty string for the last `...\n`:

```
>>> 'last\n'.split('\n')
['last', '']
>>> 'last\n'.splitlines()
['last']
```

This is explicitly mentioned in the [`str.splitlines()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

> Unlike `split()` when a delimiter string *sep* is given, this method returns an empty list for the empty string, and a terminal line break does not result in an extra line.

If there is no trailing newline, the output is identical:

```
>>> 'last'.split('\n')
['last']
>>> 'last'.splitlines()
['last']
```

In other words, `str.split()` doesn't add *anything*, but `str.splitlines()` does remove.

Comment: thank you so much!your answer is also very useful!and i learned something new from your answer!